# Pandas: explode by year-month then fill in gap

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe where each row is uniquely identified by {city name, mayor name, mayor term}. For example:

```
    city       mayor    month-year start    month-year end
0   New York    A          2000.01              2001.01
1   New York    B          2001.07              2003.05
2   New York    C          2003.12              2004.10
3   Seattle     D          2000.02              2002.03
4   Seattle     E          2002.03              2005.09
5   Seattle     A          2005.10              2006.12
```

generated by

```
d = {'city': ['New York', 'New York', 'New York', 'Seattle', 'Seattle', 'Seattle'], 'mayor': ['A','B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'A'], 'month-year start': ['2000.01', '2001.07', '2003.12', '2000.02', '2002.03', '2005.10'], 'month-year end': ['2001.01', '2003.05', '2004.10', '2002.03', '2005.09', '2006.12']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

I would like to convert this dataset to show for each city each year-month, who the mayor is:

```
city         year-month     mayor
New York       2000.01       A
New York       2000.02       A
...
New York       2001.01       A
New York       2001.02       Empty
New York       2001.03       Empty
...
New York       2001.06       Empty
New York       2001.07       B
New York       2001.08       B
...
```

**Question 1.** I know how to explode between two numbers, but is there a way to explode between the two columns of `month-year start` and `month-year end`?

**Question 2.** Since there may be gaps between two mayors, how can I fill in the gaps after exploding?

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we use `melt` to un-pivot year-start and year-end to one column. Then we groupby on `city, mayor` and `resample` to daily:

```
df = (
    df.melt(id_vars=['city', 'mayor'])
    .sort_values(['city', 'mayor'])
    .drop(columns='variable')
    .reset_index(drop=True)
)
df = df.groupby(['city', 'mayor']).resample('d', on='value').first()
df = df.drop(columns=df.columns).reset_index()
```

```
          city mayor      value
0     New York     A 2000-01-01
1     New York     A 2000-01-02
2     New York     A 2000-01-03
3     New York     A 2000-01-04
4     New York     A 2000-01-05
...        ...   ...        ...
3806   Seattle     E 2005-08-28
3807   Seattle     E 2005-08-29
3808   Seattle     E 2005-08-30
3809   Seattle     E 2005-08-31
3810   Seattle     E 2005-09-01

[3811 rows x 3 columns]
```

Comment: Thank you!! This works perfectly to expand rows within a mayor's term. Is there a way to fill in gaps between two consecutive mayors?